# Get a pass or failed using multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets

My formula displays "PASS" or "FAILED" based on multiple criteria. The problem is that it displays "PASS" even though the cells G2 to I2 are blank. The desired behavior is that it should display "Pass" when G2 to I2 has values of not greater than 0.28 but not lesser than -0.28, otherwise if it is greater than 0.28 and lesser than -0.28 it should display "failed". As well as if the M2 has text it should also display "failed". How do I make that happen?

Here is my formula:

=IF(and(G2<0.28, H2<0.28, I2<0.28, G2>-0.28, H2>-0.28, I2>-0.28,ISBLANK(M2)),"PASS","FAILED")

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(AND(G2< 0.28, H2< 0.28, I2< 0.28, 
        G2>-0.28, H2>-0.28, I2>-0.28,
        G2<>"",   H2<>"",   I2<>"", ISBLANK(M2)), "PASS", "FAILED")
```